# ¿Cómo editar posición de .rptdesign antes de imprimir?

Tags: php

Estoy desarrollando un sistema web y los reportes los realizó en Birt, el único problema es que existe una plantilla predefinida para dicho reporte y la impresión varia en base a la impresora utilizada. 
Quisiera encontrar un método para pre visualizar la impresión y poder mover algunos componentes en el eje X o Y antes de imprimir.
Me sería de mucha ayuda sus consejos.